# WPF binding source mismatch for a MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown inside a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mahapps.metro, lost-focus

I often use `MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown` to manipulate numerical values from the user interface. Recently I have observed a binding behaviour so strange and surreal that completely undermined my faith in the WPF binding infrastructure.

The phenomenon occurred with a collection of view models bound to the `ItemsSource` of a `TabControl`. Within each of these view models, there is a property of type `int` that I bind to the `Value` property of a `MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown`. I noticed that when I manipulate a `NumericUpDown` through its `TextBox` and leave the focus there just before I select a new tab in the `TabControl`, the value I have just set gets written into the `NumericUpDown` **inside the new tab being selected**. That is clearly undesirable as that tab contains a value I did not intend to overwrite just by selecting the containing tab.

This only occurs if I use the `TextBox` part to set the value, and not when I use the `+` and `-` buttons. Furthermore, taking the focus from the `NumericUpDown` prevents the bug from occurring. Hooking into the `LostFocus` event of the `NumericUpDown`, I could observe that the binding source of the respective binding had already changed to that within the view model associated with the next tab (instead of that associated with the `NumericUpDown` actually firing the `LostFocus` event), and that explains the surreal value bleed. (Additionally, it gets fired twice, as you will be able to see in the MWE.)

I could find a workaround by registering for the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the tab label and setting the focus to another element programmatically before the tab switch actually occurs. Still, as I said, this undermined my confidence in the WPF binding architecture. Is it a general WPF binding bug or is it specific to `MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown`? What can I do to ensure such bugs do not occur in my code (apart from the amateur workaround I could come up with)?

The XAML part of the MWE:

```
<Window x:Class="NumericUpDownMWE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mahApps="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NumericUpDownMWE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Text="Value" />
                        <mahApps:NumericUpDown
                            LostFocus="HandleLostFocus"
                            Value="{Binding Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The respective code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace NumericUpDownMWE
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ExampleViewModel();
        }

        private void HandleLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement? frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            BindingExpression? bindingExpression = frameworkElement?.GetBindingExpression(MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown.ValueProperty);
            string? sourceName = (bindingExpression?.ResolvedSource as ExampleItem)?.Name;
        }
    }

    public class ExampleItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int value;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public string Name { get; }

        public int Value {
            get { return value; }
            set {
                if (value != this.value) {
                    this.value = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
                }
            }
        }

        public ExampleItem(string name, int value)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<ExampleItem> Items { get; }

        public ExampleViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ExampleItem>() {
                new ExampleItem("Item A", 1),
                new ExampleItem("Item B", 2),
                new ExampleItem("Item C", 3)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it also happen with a TextBox instead of NumericUpDown? What if you bind like `{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` to avoid the LostFocus behaviour?

Comment: I have tried `{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` just to make sure (though I suspect it is the default) and the problem persisted. Setting `{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}` prevented it, but it was highly cumbersome to set the value afterwards, having to find a focusable control and manually set the focus there to have the changes actually take effect.

Comment: @Clemens: No, a simple `TextBox` does not behave like this, I have just tried. Just that of a `NumericUpDown`.

Comment: Then at least the answer to the question *Is it a general WPF binding bug or is it specific to MahApps.Metro.Controls.NumericUpDown?* seems clear. No idea if it's feasible, but you could try some other NumericUpDown implementation - if there is one.